# Coldfusion 80 labels template

Tags: html, css, coldfusion

I am trying to create a label template to print labels. I am using coldfusion and when the user clicks a button it will prompt them what number they would like to start with and it will print the labels starting at that number and loop through 80 times because of how many labels are on the sheet. I am trying to set up the generate_labels.cfm and cannot get the labels to match up correctly.

Right now this is what have come up with just trying to show all 80 labels in the correct layout and format and am struggling tremendously.

I have been following this step by step http://www.bennadel.com/blog/922-ask-ben-printing-shipping-labels-with-coldfusion.htm and with this template http://www.avery.com/avery/en_us/Templates-%26-Software/Templates/Labels/Return-Address-Labels/Return-Address-Label-80-per-sheet_Microsoft-Word.htm

(It is supposed to be 4 across with spaces and 20 rows with spaces. A total of 80 labels)

This is what I am coming up with:[image]

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
            Content-Location: file:///C:/1E42A1F3/DealerLabels.htm
            Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
            Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

        <html
            xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
            xmlns:w=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
            xmlns:dt=3D"uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"
            xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

        <head>
            <meta http-equiv=3DContent-Type content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dus-ascii">
            <meta name=3DProgId content=3DWord.Document>
            <meta name=3DGenerator content=3D"Microsoft Word 14">
            <meta name=3DOriginator content=3D"Microsoft Word 14">
            <link rel=3DFile-List href=3D"DealerLabels_files/filelist.xml">


            <style>
            @font-face
                {font-family:Calibri;
                panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;
                mso-font-charset:0;
                mso-generic-font-family:swiss;
                mso-font-pitch:variable;
                mso-font-signature:-536870145 1073786111 1 0 415 0;}

            p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
                {mso-style-unhide:no;
                mso-style-qformat:yes;
                mso-style-parent:"";
                margin-top:0in;
                margin-right:0in;
                margin-bottom:10.0pt;
                margin-left:0in;
                line-height:115%;
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                font-size:11.0pt;
                font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
                mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";}
            p.AveryStyle1, li.AveryStyle1, div.AveryStyle1
                {mso-style-name:"Avery Style 1";
                mso-style-priority:99;
                mso-style-unhide:no;
                mso-style-parent:"";
                margin-top:1.45pt;
                margin-right:1.4pt;
                margin-bottom:1.45pt;
                margin-left:1.4pt;
                text-align:center;
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                font-size:8.0pt;
                mso-bidi-font-size:11.0pt;
                font-family:"Arial","sans-serif";
                mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman";
                color:black;
                mso-bidi-font-weight:bold;}
            @page WordSection1
                {size:8.5in 11.0in;
                margin:.5in 22.3pt 30.0pt 27.85pt;
                mso-header-margin:0in;
                mso-footer-margin:0in;
                mso-paper-source:0;}
            div.WordSection1
                {page:WordSection1;}

            table.MsoNormalTable
                {mso-style-name:"Table Normal";
                mso-tstyle-rowband-size:0;
                mso-tstyle-colband-size:0;
                mso-style-noshow:yes;
                mso-style-priority:99;
                mso-style-qformat:yes;
                mso-style-parent:"";
                mso-padding-alt:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;
                mso-para-margin:0in;
                mso-para-margin-bottom:.0001pt;
                mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
                font-size:10.0pt;
                font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body lang=3DEN-US style=3D'tab-interval:.5in'>


            <div class=3DWordSection1>


                <table 
                    class=3DMsoNormalTable 
                    border=3D0 
                    cellspacing=3D0 
                    cellpadding=3D0
                    style=3D'border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-layout-alt:fixed;mso-padding-alt:0in 5.75pt 0in 5.75pt'>


                    <tr style=3D'mso-yfti-irow:0;mso-yfti-firstrow:yes;height:.5in;mso-height-rule:exactly'>
                    <cfoutput> 


                         <!--- 
                             Instead of looping over a query as we probably 
                             would want to do, we are going to loop over an 
                             index array and just repeat the same address 
                             over and over again; we are just demonstrating 
                             label printing with ColdFusion and MS Word - 
                             we don't need real addresses. 
                         ---> 
                         <cfloop 
                             index="intI" 
                             from="1" 
                             to="20" 
                             step="1"> 


                            <td 
                                width=3D168 
                                style=3D'width:1.75in;padding:0in 5.75pt 0in 5.75pt;height:.5in'>
                                 <p class=3DAveryStyle1>1</p> 


                             </td> 

                             <td 
                                width=3D29 
                                rowspan=3D20 
                                valign=3Dtop 
                                style=3D'width:.3in;border-top:solid white 1.0pt;'>

                                <p class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

                            </td>


                             <td 
                                width=3D168 
                                style=3D'width:1.75in;padding:0in 5.75pt 0in 5.75pt;height:.5in'>
                                 <p class=3DAveryStyle1>2</p> 


                             </td>

                             <td 
                                width=3D29 
                                rowspan=3D20 
                                valign=3Dtop 
                                style=3D'width:.3in;border-top:solid white 1.0pt;
                                        border-left:none;border-bottom:solid white 1.0pt;'>

                                <p class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

                            </td>

                            <td 
                                width=3D168 
                                style=3D'width:1.75in;padding:0in 5.75pt 0in 5.75pt;height:.5in'>
                                 <p class=3DAveryStyle1>3</p> 


                             </td> 

                             <td 
                                width=3D29 
                                rowspan=3D20 
                                valign=3Dtop 
                                style=3D'width:.3in;border-top:solid white 1.0pt;
                                        border-left:none;border-bottom:solid white 1.0pt;'>

                                <p class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

                            </td>


                             <td 
                                width=3D168 
                                style=3D'width:1.75in;padding:0in 5.75pt 0in 5.75pt;height:.5in'>
                                 <p class=3DAveryStyle1>4</p> 


                             </td>

                             <td 
                                width=3D29 
                                rowspan=3D20 
                                valign=3Dtop 
                                style=3D'width:.3in;border-top:solid white 1.0pt;
                                        border-left:none;border-bottom:solid white 1.0pt;'>

                                <p class=3DMsoNormal><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>

                            </td>

                            </tr> 

                            <tr style=3D'mso-yfti-irow:#intI#;height:.5in;mso-height-rule:exactly'>


                                 <!--- In between each row is a spacer row. --->




                         </cfloop> 
                         <!--- End address loop. ---> 


                     </cfoutput> 


                 </tr> 
             </table> 


             <p class=3DMsoNormal align=3Dcenter style=3D'text-align:center'> 
                 <span style=3D'font-size:12.0pt;mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;layout-grid-mode:line'><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span> 
             </p>


    </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont see any ColdFusion code.  All  see is what appears to be something saved as html in MS Word.

Comment: there is a loop in the table I was trying to create a loop for it

Comment: I tested Ben's HTML template file using WKHTMLTOPDF and the results weren't usable as the MS-HTML is invalid and doesn't translate well to PDF.  I guess you need to render & print this using IE. (I uploaded the file to my webserver and ran WKHTMLTOPDF http://www.website.com/labels.htm labels.pdf)  You may need to clean up the template a bit. If using CF9, font/CSS support is limited.

Comment: You may also need to deal with text-overflow issues... I have some sample user data that won't fit on a label nicely due to length.  CSS3 makes it easy to truncate or resize if bounds are exceed, but this may not work with CFPDF depending upon which version you are using.  (I've noticed that most ColdFusion questions never mention version. CF is buggy. Version is important when dealing with PDF.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quite a lot easier if you make a fillable PDF than a DOC with ColdFusion's `<cfpdfform action="populate">` with much more reliable output.  Search for a PDF template for Avery 80 label, and make it fillable if it isn't already.

http://cfdocs.org/cfpdfform

Comment: This method is difficult if the labels need to be unique.  Unique labels would require that each field have a separate/unique field name.

Comment: It's not that hard to have unique field names. Worse come to worse, use a cfloop to init all 80 labels.

Comment: It's not hard... "after you've correctly created the initial template."  I recently generated some PDF tickets and resorted to using iText's PDFStamper feature versus having to staticly update PDF form field values.

Comment: Java can also be used... http://www.datavirtue.com/Software/dev/PDFLabels.java (note: this sample would need to be modified to be used w/ColdFusion and is similar to what I used for my ticketing PDF.)